# Remove unwanted horizontal scroll (Where is the horizontal scroll coming from?)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, user-interface, frontend

I am noticing that my react application has an unwanted horizontal scroll. I see that if I comment out the `<About/>` component then the scroll disappears. Not sure as to why it is getting added.  It goes away if I add `overflow-x: hidden` to `App.css` but it doesnt seem like the right solution.

Also, I se that `<About/>`= **BLUE** component is coming on the **RED** part. I am not able to understand why it is happening.

Appreciate any help.

These are the files and the[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJEzv.png):

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Landing from "./Components/Landing";
import About from "./Components/About";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Landing />
      <About />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**App.css**

```
.App {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 900px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: lightpink;
}
```

**Landing.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./Landing.css";

function Landing() {
  return (
    <div className="LandingContainer"></div>
}
export default Landing;
```

**Landing.css**

```
.LandingContainer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

**About.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./About.css";

function About() {
  return (
    <div className="MainAboutContainer"></div>
}
export default About;
```

**About.css**

```
.MainAboutContainer {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

the easiest answer is to put `overflow-x:none` in your `App.css` .

Answer (score 7):

Do you have any other css enabled?

If not, try adding following in your `App.css`:

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  /* this makes sure the padding and the border is included in the box sizing */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

html body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: inherit;
}
```

Additionally, you shouldn't add `height: 100%` to both of your `Landing` and `About` element, it will double your app's height.

## Edit

Try this, it'll remove the horizontal scroll and weird padding problem:

#### App.css

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  /* this makes sure the padding and the border is included in the box sizing */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

html body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: inherit;
}

.App {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 900px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: lightpink;
}
```

#### Landing.css

```css
.LandingContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

#### About.css

```css
.MainAboutContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: If I add the CSS you suggested to App.js then it doesnt even display About component. Could you please elaborate on why adding 100% to both Landing and About will double height? Arent they separate components?

Comment: Oh, I might be misunderstood. If they're separated components, you can't expect them to stack one on another, you need to give them `position: absolute` to achieve that

Comment: I dont want them to be stacked at all. I want them to be separate. But it seems like About (blue) is overlapping onto Landing (green)

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your App.css

```
body {
  overflow-y: hidden; /* Hide vertical scrollbar */
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Hide horizontal scrollbar */
}
```